# CreateJS play child movieClip timeline

Tags: javascript, html, flash, canvas, createjs

I REALLY REALLY want to like CreateJS, but it is infuriating that basic things in AS3 are not working or are not capable.  Here is a quick example:

I have a simple animation in a MovieClip, a circle moving from right to left.  I have a

```
this.stop();
```

on the first frame and then a

```
this.stop();
```

on the last frame.

I drag that mc out to the main timeline, give it an instance of "main_mc" then create a function called init()

```
function init()
{
  this.main_mc.play();
}

init();
```

This is the error I get:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

@thatkidrich The problem is that "this" is scoped to the window and your 'main_mc' doesn't live on the window object. To reference your instance you will have to go through the 'exportRoot' object which will give you a reference to all your instance that you currently have on your FLA stage. I also wouldn't suggest coding your JS within the FLA, I would only use the exported JS for constructing assets. In your case I would control 'main_mc' via code outside within the HTML.

Example:

```
function init() {
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 exportRoot = new lib.Balltimeline();

 stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
 stage.addChild(exportRoot);
 stage.update();

 //This will give you a reference to your MC on stage.
 var mc = exportRoot.main_mc;
 mc.play();

 createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
 createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
```

}